# I have a photo taken with a cell phone in the dark the subject is unrecognizable how do i edit this to see what was in the photo?

Tags: editing

The photo was taken with a cell phone in the dark.. the subject is unrecognizable when I start adding brightness contrast and highlights it makes it too pixily and even more confusing! What order would I start applying the adjustments? I dont want a great photo I just want to know what is in it? Is this possible? The background is black and the subject a grey color

Comment: You probably can't do anything to improve the photo.

Comment: Without seeing the photo, there's no way anyone can give you any useful advice.

Comment: Real life isn't a Hollywood spy movie. While it is possible to bring out shadow detail in a photo, a photo that only records black can't magically be "enhanced".

Comment: Having said that, on a computer, you could try playing around with the levels / curves / midtones / grey point / gamma setting to see if you can bring out any extra detail in the picture. For example, there's a guide from Adobe for Photoshop here: [https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/levels-adjustment.html](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/levels-adjustment.html)

Comment: Please, send the image and I will try to make it recognizable. If possible, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is visible when playing around with simple contrast and brightness settings we may have to admit it's because there isn't anything there. If SOMETHING is revealed, it may be worth trying the more advanced controls in an image editing program.  Can you post the picture?